# Functions Questions

Tags: functions

1. Suppose the domain of $f$ is $(-1,1)$. Define the function $\ell$ by
   $$\ell(x)=f\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right).$$
   What is the domain of $\ell$?
2. Some functions that aren't invertible can be made invertible by restricting their domains. For example, the function $x^2$ is invertible if we restrict $x$ to the interval $[0,\infty)$, or to any subset of that interval. In that case, the inverse function is $\sqrt x$. (We could also restrict $x^2$ to the domain $(-\infty,0]$, in which case the inverse function would be $-\sqrt{x}$.)

   Similarly, by restricting the domain of the function $f(x) = 2x^2-4x-5$ to an interval, we can make it invertible. What is the largest such interval that includes the point $x=0$?

On the first question, I got the answer (0,1), which is wrong. On the second question, I got $(-\infty,1)$ which is also wrong.

EDIT: I think the answer to 1. is (-1,1). Is this right???

Comment: Can you explain *how* you're getting your answers?

Comment: In 1 if x=0.9 then x+1/x-1 is -19.  Is that in the domain of f?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
 -1 < \frac{x+1}{x-1} < 1
 \\ \implies  -2 < \frac{2}{x-1} < 0
\end{eqnarray*}$$
so the domain is $(-\infty, 0)$

For the second one , the interval  $(-\infty, 1] $ is slightly larger than the one you suggested.